# Grails app package to war using maven

Tags: maven, grails, gradle

I need to build a Grails 3.x application using the company build server,
that allows only maven based builds.

Is is possible to build, and package to war, a Grails 3 application using maven, and how to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a grails-maven plugin but [it doesn't works with grails 3](https://github.com/grails/grails-maven/issues/72).

I finally solved using the [gradle-maven-plugin](https://github.com/if6was9/gradle-maven-plugin) >= 1.0.7 (thanks to [Graeme Rocher](https://github.com/graemerocher) for the suggestion).

In order to get maven build your grails app you must:

**1 - Create a pom.xml file like this**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
<groupId>org.mypackage</groupId>
<artifactId>mywebapp</artifactId>
<packaging>jar</packaging>
<version>0.0.1</version>
<name>my web app</name>
<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.fortasoft</groupId>
            <artifactId>gradle-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>1.0.7</version>
            <configuration>
                <tasks>
                    <!-- this would effectively call "gradle war" -->
                    <task>war</task>
                </tasks>
            </configuration>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <!-- You can bind this to any phase you like -->
                    <phase>compile</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <!-- goal must be "invoke" -->
                        <goal>invoke</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
</project>
```

**2 - Add the jcenter maven repository to your maven configuration**

The latest plugin build [is available only here](https://bintray.com/robschoening/gradle-maven-plugin/gradle-maven-plugin/).

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?>
<settings xsi:schemaLocation='http://maven.apache.org/SETTINGS/1.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/settings-1.0.0.xsd' xmlns='http://maven.apache.org/SETTINGS/1.0.0' xmlns:xsi='http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance'>
<profiles>
<profile>
    <repositories>
        <repository>
            <snapshots>
                <enabled>false</enabled>
            </snapshots>
            <id>bintray-robschoening-gradle-maven-plugin</id>
            <name>bintray</name>
            <url>http://dl.bintray.com/robschoening/gradle-maven-plugin</url>
        </repository>
    </repositories>
    <pluginRepositories>
        <pluginRepository>
            <snapshots>
                <enabled>false</enabled>
            </snapshots>
            <id>bintray-robschoening-gradle-maven-plugin</id>
            <name>bintray-plugins</name>
            <url>http://dl.bintray.com/robschoening/gradle-maven-plugin</url>
        </pluginRepository>
    </pluginRepositories>
    <id>bintray</id>
</profile>
</profiles>
<activeProfiles>
    <activeProfile>bintray</activeProfile>
</activeProfiles>
</settings>
```

**2 [Alternative] - Build the plugin from sources**

```
git clone https://github.com/if6was9/gradle-maven-plugin.git
## build and install it locally
mvn install
```

**3 - Run `mvn package`** to build your grails application

The maven plugin will automatically execute the gradle wrapper inside the grails application to build it. The application war will be located inside `build/libs` directory.